# Python-3.x: Passing live data between user defined classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python
Assume the following

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.X = "A"
       #init whatever I need to make this work

   def Areturn(self)
       return self.x

class B:
   def __init__(self):
       self.Y = "B"
       #initi whatever I need to make this work

   def Bset(self. sender)
       self.Y = sender
```

So now do the following:

```
A.x = "QQQ"
B.Bset(A.Areturn)

A.X = "ZZZ"
```

Now what I want to do is NOT have to call `B.Bset(A.Areturn`) in order to get `self.Y` updated. In another words, I don't want to have to "refresh" `B` explicitly every time `A` changes. Ideally, something like an implicit (defined in `B.__init__`) flag that says, for this instance, if the value of `A` changes, trigger `B` to evaluate. Almost like a "depends on" relationship between `A` and `B` for a given instance of each.

Suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to require that `A` receives an instance of `B` in its constructor, you can simply use the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator for this:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, b):
       self._x = "A"
       self.b = b

   @property
   def x(self):
       return self._x

   @x.setter
   def x(self, val):
       self._x = val
       self.b.Y = val

class B:
   def __init__(self):
       self.Y = "B"
```

If you want something more generic (so that `A` doesn't need to know about `B` at creation time), you can provide a way for any object to register to be updated when `A.x` changes:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self._x = "A"
       self._x_listeners = []

   @property
   def x(self):
       return self._x

   @x.setter
   def x(self, val):
       self._x = val
       # Update the correct attribute for all listening objects
       for listener in self._x_listeners:
          setattr(listener[0], listener[1], val)

   def register_x_listener(self, obj, prop):
       # obj is the object to update, prop is the property on that object.
       self._x_listeners.append((obj, prop))

class B:
   def __init__(self):
       self.Y = "B"

a = A()
b = B()
a.register_x_listener(b, 'Y') # Now b.Y will be updated when a.x changes.
print(a.x)
print(b.Y)
a.x = 5 
print(a.x)
print(b.Y)
```

Output:

```
A
B
5
5
```